# IIF statement using BETWEEN

Tags: reporting-services

The following IIF expression isn't working for me:

```
IIF(Fields!Number.Value BETWEEN 1 AND 1000, Fields!Number.Value, "all ok")
```

Basically I want to list the value if it falls within 1 and 1000 and show 'all ok' if it doesn't.

Please can you advise where I've gone wrong as this is throwing an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSRS does not support `BETWEEN` as far as I can tell.

[image]

Just use equivalent `>=` and `<=` checks:

```
=IIf(Fields!Number.Value >= 1 and Fields!Number.Value <= 1000
  , Fields!Number.Value
  , "All OK")
```

Comment: That's disappointing, but it does seem like this is the best option. Kicking it old-school!